# Check for File in multiple directories with an IF statement Powershell

Tags: powershell, directory, get-childitem

I am facing some problems in powershell. I want to be able to let a powershell command search for multiple directories. 
With the name being a variable like "$VM_DISK=VM_DISK.vhdx" and let powershell search in that manor so that if that file exists in a folder such as C:\VM_DISK\ it exit the script. 
I have already tried the "Get-Childitem" but it doesn't seem to work when I put my variable in it. Here is an example:

```
    $VM_DISK= "Example.vhdx"

    $search=Get-ChildItem -Path C:\VM_DISK\* -Filter $VM_DISK -Recurse 

    if ($search -eq $VM_DISK) {write-host "Goodbye!" exit}  else {write-host "Continue"}
```

I just cant seem to figure out why this isn't working, hope some can figure it out.

Comment: `if($VM_DISK){...}` - if `Get-ChildItem` didn't return anything, `$VM_DISK` is empty and will evaluate to `$false`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The peculiar thing is when I put a variable in front of the Get-Childitem it doesn't work anymore and when I remove it I do get a response that the file exists with location and all.

Comment: Sorry, i meant `if($search){...}` - `$search` will contain the result (or nothing) from `Get-ChildItem`

Comment: Your absolutely right, I do get the repsonse "Great" but how can I let the if statement be equal to the $VM_DISK  variable? Like " if($search -eq $VM_DISk) {..}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to alter your `if` statement.

```
if ($search.Name -contains $VM_Disk)
```

This way you are comparing an Array of names (which is what you want, names of objects, not objects) to a name of particular object (to a `string`, basically).
This makes little sense in your case, tbh. Since `$search` would always include `$VM_Disk` or would be null if nothing was found.

So the proper way to test would be `if ($search)` (just like Mathias advised). Which would test if anything was returned. Which, basically equals what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you verry much,indeed. This was the solution I needed I just got a bit stuck and couldn't find the right terms but with your help I can finally move on with my project.

Comment: Do you also know how to check for multiple files? Like in I want to search for file VM_NAME.vhdx and VM_NAME 2.vhdx?

Comment: you want both of them to be in `$search` or any of them?

Comment: I want it to have it so if both files exist it quits the script I tried putting it in search with the include function instead of the filter function. After that i made an if statement like if ($search.name,search2.name -contains  $VM_NAME,$VM_NAME 2 ) {exit}

Comment: `if ($search.name -contains $VM_NAME -and $search.name -contains $VM_NAME2)`

Comment: $search=Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Map\* -include $VM_NAME.vhdx,$VM_NAME2.vhdx -Recurse
if ($search.Name -contains $VM_NAME.vhdx -and $search.Name -contains $VM_NAME2.vhdx) {write-host "True"} else {write-host "False"} It still returns a false? Even when they exist?

Comment: why are you using `$VM_NAME.vhdx`?

Comment: It is not necessary anymore I added a filter with *.vhdx so that is now removed but I do stil get a false error. If I run the Get-Childitems on it own you do see the VM_NAME and VM_NAME 2 not literally of course but it shows the files with the name are there.

Comment: I'm honestly a bit lost at this point, can you create a new question with your errors. its kinda hard to gather information across your comments ;)

Comment: I made a new question :)