# Max 2 files in the directory, check with an If statement

Tags: powershell

As response on my last question  ([Check for File in multiple directories with an IF statement Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849639/check-for-file-in-multiple-directories-with-an-if-statement-powershell/40849926?noredirect=1#comment68920611_40849926)) , I am still left with a question I will show the code first:

```
 $VM_NAME= "Machine"
 $VM_NAME2="$VM_NAME 2"

 $search=Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Map\* -include $VM_NAME,$VM_NAME2 -filter *.vhdx -Recurse 
if ($search.Name -contains $VM_NAME.vhdx -and $search.Name -contains $VM_NAME2.vhdx) {write-host "True" exit} else {write-host "False"}
```

This code gives me a True, even though I removed 1 file, how can I make sure that it goes to false so that the script continues instead of exits. 
The point of doing this is to make sure on a webpage I created when people run the script they don't create more than 2 files.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: hrm, I'm not sure what is going on, try `if ($search.Name -contains "$VM_NAME.vhdx" -and $search.Name -contains "$VM_NAME2.vhdx")`, also, there's a typo, `write-host "True"; exit`, you forgot the `;`.

Comment: I didn't even see the typo haha. I found the solution in the Get-ChildItem I needed to add an .vhdx extension after the $VM_NAME,$VM_NAME2. I tested it by deleting a file and adding it back and it now gives true and false so. Thanks for the support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are comparing the property `.Name` of `$search` with the property `.vhdx` of `$VM_Name`, the second property does not exist.  you just need to format your comparison so that you compare `$search.Name` with a string representing the name of the vm followed by '.vhdx' like so `$search.Name -contains "$($VM_NAME).vhdx"`do the same with $VM_Name2

Comment: Thank you, I figured some of the bits out myself but this certainly helped me understand. Just added some experience to my learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

modify like this

```
$VM_NAME= "res"
$VM_NAME2="$VM_NAME 2"

# -> if contains $VM_NAME2="$VM_NAME 2" then it contains $VM_NAME
# -> test BaseName = test whitout extension
$search=(gci C:\Map\* -File -filter *.vhdx -Recurse | select @{N="Val";E={$_.BaseName -like "*$VM_NAME2*" }} ).Val
$search -contains $true
```

Comment: Somehow that doesn't seem to do the trick, my code is as followed but even though the files exists it keeps saying succeeded.  param ([string] $VM_NAME)
$VM_NAME2 = "$VM_NAME 2"

$search=Get-ChildItem -Path "\\192.168.100.58\Virtualservers\Disk's\*" -include "$VM_NAME.vhdx","$VM_NAME2".vhdx -filter *.vhdx -Recurse 
if ($search.Name -contains "$($VM_NAME).vhdx" -and $search.Name -contains "$($VM_NAME2).vhdx") {exit} else {write-host "Check succeeded"}